# +ex {"La conversión especificada no es válida."} System.Exception {System.InvalidCastException}

Tags: c#, excel, asp.net-mvc

Estoy haciendo la carga de un archivo de Excel a mi web, en MVC.Net utilizando la libreria ClosedXML. La carga la logro hacer únicamente cuando defino mis columnas de tipo string, pero hay columnas que por fuerza deben ser tipo int o float ya que esta información será transportada a una base de datos (ya lo logro hacer solo cuando son de tipo string). Muestro un poco de mi código:

```
 if (ws.Cell(row, 1).Value != null)
     model.LineaNivel3 = ws.Cell(row, 1).Value.ToString().Trim();

 if (ws.Cell(row, 2).Value != null)
     model.LineaNivel4 = ws.Cell(row, 2).Value.ToString().Trim();

 if (ws.Cell(row, 3).Value != null)
     model.Banco = (int)ws.Cell(row, 3).Value;
```

Tanto la columna 1 como 2 no tengo ningún problema, me lee la información al leer la columna de banco me manda a la excepción y no logro mostrar el archivo en la web.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A través de un punto de depuración he ido leyendo línea por línea, al llegar aquí me lo muestra de esta forma y me manda al catch. ¿Cuál sería la forma más adecuada en como declarar model.Banco? Banco es una columna tipo int.

Comment: Ya intentaste int.Parse() o Convert.ToInt16()?

Comment: Había intentado con ToInt32 y con Parse. Con ToInt16 lo pude hacer, gracias.

Comment: En caso que sean float o números largos tipo bigint, ¿cùal me recomendarias utilizar?

Comment: Si hubieras dejado el código de la clase de `model` sería más claro el problema. No podemos adivinar que `model.Banco` es un entero, un short o lo que fuese.

Comment: Ya lo agregue. Mis disculpas por haber pasado por alto eso.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final pude hacer la carga de esta manera con los valores que no son string:

```
if (ws.Cell(row, 4).Value != null)
    model.LineaNivel4 = ws.Cell(row, 4).Value.ToString().Trim();

if (ws.Cell(row, 5).Value != null)
    model.LineaNivel5 = ws.Cell(row, 5).Value.ToString().Trim();

if (ws.Cell(row, 6).Value != null)
    model.Banco = Convert.ToInt16(ws.Cell(row, 6).Value.ToString().Trim());
```

Declaración del modelo:

```
public string LineaNivel4 { get; set; }
public string LineaNivel5 { get; set; }
public int Banco { get; set; }
```

Así lo logre cargar dentro de mi MVC.NET
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y así trasladado a mi BD con su respectivo tipo de dato.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]